# Useless tag [routines]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just came across a question tagged with a generic looking tag: [routines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routines). Further inspection of its [tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/routines) reveals the tag has no wiki, and is primarily used by low-rep users as a catch-all "solve my problem for me".

Since this tag clearly serves no purpose, it should be removed.

Comment: "A catch-all" -- gotta admire [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714430/export-phpmyadmin-database-without-procedures-by-mistake) for sheer ballsiness. "[tag:export], [tag:phpmyadmin], [tag:database], [tag:procedure], [tag:ssh], [tag:sql], [tag:restore] ... *so many to choose from*. Let's pick [tag:routines] then."

Comment: @Jongware Turns out one of those tags was applied, [then removed by another user](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24714430/revisions).

Comment: @Duncan: I'm not an expert in any of these tags, but if that one was irrelevant, one may then ask why it was left in the title. Bit of a quick fix, methinks. (I only checked if any other word than 'routine' was an existing tag.)

Comment: @Jongware Completely agree, it was a crap edit by said person. It's also a bad question, so I've voted to close.

Comment: In some kinds of software word routine can have specific meaning, like intersystems cache routines for example http://docs.intersystems.com/cache41/prg/prgroutines.html